# WCF C# Service not functioning correctly during logon and Logoff event

Tags: c#, wcf, service

We have written a Windows Service (c#) that monitors the OnSessionChange Event; this is used to despatch a message to a remote server to record the Logon, Logoff, screen Lock and Unlock events of users.

All has been working fine on Windows XP however we have migrated the service to Windows 7 and are now finding that the WCF call during a sessionChange of type Logon or Logoff is not successfully reaching the server. The code follows the same path and works fine for Lock and Unlock events. It's just the logon and logoff events that go AWOL.

The ServiceContract is configured as a OneWay method, lots of logging has been added to the client and it appears that from that nothing has gone wrong, we still trap the event and locally (in the event log) record the action, it just doesn't reach the server.

Comment: Trt to [configure tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms733025.aspx) to show WCF internal logs.

Comment: There are lots of posts about OnSessionChange not working correctly...